# Automatically click the button on a page that is not mine

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to put code from another page on my page with php:

```
$url="site_url.html";
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$ch1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$page=curl_exec($ch1);
```

The code works, but...
I need to click a button that is in the code automatically. Clicking on my page does not work correctly. It only works on the original page. How can I do this work?
Thank you

Comment: clicking a button can mean anything... It could help to provide the code. Also do I get it right that you download a page from a different web server and then render it as your own? what the **** makes you do that?

Comment: @slepic Please, think a bit of time before you do such comments.
I do not want to use the code as if it were mine. I want to use de information in this code only.
If I wanted to use a page like the original I would use an iframe

Comment: @Dharman Is there any other way to get information from another page that is not mine?
The information I need appears only after a click on a specific button.
Is there any way to do this click automatically?

Comment: sry, it wasnt the f word, it was the h word, and yet I considered it too much so I censored myself :D Anyway, what happens when you click the button? does it call an ajax request to obtain the information or where does the information get from? you should look for that instead of trying to push a button :)

Comment: @slepic I think I'm stuck. Function is executed onclick identified with the class "phone-button".

```
$(".phone-button").on("click",function(){
 function next_frame(){   $placeholder.text((Math.random()+"").substr(-7)),timeout=setTimeout(next_frame,50)
  }
  var timeout=null,$button=$(this),$placeholder=$(".placeholder",$button);
  var $modal=modal("phone",{body:rot13($button.data("phone"))}).on("loaded.bs.modal",function(){clearTimeout(timeout);
  var $contact_panel=$(".panel.contact"),$phone_parent=$(".jumbotron .btn-group",$modal),
  phone=$("h1",$modal).text()||"";
  
})
```

Comment: @oliver_33 What is the definition of the modal function? Can you check if there is a new ajax request when you click the button in the network panel of your browser?

Comment: @slepic Yes, I see it! :D
But de request has a body=FIeIsMG3GWu5RMiBbyc8hmlzS7EpHWBGKu2i/wv4FtrDVXfMfpgy73P036fxhtPtTkD=
and in elements has a phone-data="SVrVfZT3TJh5EZvOolp8uzymF7RcUJOTXh2v/ji4SgeQIKsZsctl73C036skugCgGxQ=". 
These keys have some similarities but I do not know how to get the right key

Comment: Try to access the url of the request with those hashes repeatedly. If you obtain the information everytime then they are just identifiers, and you can use that request url directly and those hashes will always be the same, no need to download that page at all. On the other hand, if the information is only available on first request, and then it is not available anymore, it means it is some protection hash. In that case you will have to curl the page containing this link, extract it and use the new url with fresh hashes.

Comment: @slepic I do not know if I understand very well, but this key is different for every phone number that exists.
How do I get this request automatically?
Thank you

Comment: First of all try to check if the site provider has some public api documentation, so you can see if the solution isnt there. If it wont help, create new question as this is going far from your original question...

Comment: In worst case, try this https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver

Comment: @slepic thank you for your help.
That key is really very similar. Each letter has a difference of 13 characters in the alphabet. I think it's not very smart to do it like this, but for me it was great.
 I converted the key to the key that works and I was able to get the information I wanted :D